# Trying to find closest value in BST in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

Trying to follow along with [this](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/closest-value-in-binary-search-tree-3969bf8dfb03) write up on [Find the Closest Value in a Binary Search Tree](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/closest-value-in-binary-search-tree-3969bf8dfb03). However, I am getting undefined returned instead of 13. Below is the code that also includes the tree data. The write up has an alternate more optimized solution but I'm just trying to first understand the less optimized version first. I'm missing a step but can't find it. What am I missing. Thank you.

[

```js
const treeData = {
  "target": 12,
  "tree": {
      "nodes": [
        {"id": "10", "left": "5", "right": "15", "value": 10},
        {"id": "15", "left": "13", "right": "22", "value": 15},
        {"id": "22", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 22},
        {"id": "13", "left": null, "right": "14", "value": 13},
        {"id": "14", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 14},
        {"id": "5", "left": "2", "right": "5-2", "value": 5},
        {"id": "5-2", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 5},
        {"id": "2", "left": "1", "right": null, "value": 2},
        {"id": "1", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 1}
      ],
      "root": "10"
    }
};
  
class BST {
    constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }
};


const findClosestValueInBst = (tree, target) => {
  
  // define current node as input tree
    let currentNode = tree;
  //console.log(tree);
  // create array to store BST values
  const values = [];

  // traverse the tree and place all values in the above array
    const traverse = node => {
    if (node) {
        traverse(node.left);
      values.push(node.value);
      traverse(node.right);
    }
  }
  
  traverse(tree);
  
  // create closestProximity variable
  let closestProximity = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  //console.log(closestProximity);
  // create undefined closestValue variable
  let closestValue;
  
  // iterate over the values array, checking each value's proximity to the target value
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    let proximity = Math.abs(values[i] - target);
    // if closer in proximity than closestProximity, replace closestProximity
    if (proximity < closestProximity) {
        // update closestValue
      closestValue = values[i];
    }
    
  }

 
  return closestValue;
};

const result = findClosestValueInBst(treeData.tree, treeData.target);
console.log(result);
```

][2]

Comment: `Math.abs(proximity < closestProximity)` makes no sense. You are basically doing `Math.abs(true)` and `Math.abs(false)` Do you see our typo?

Comment: Next problem, you never update `closestProximity`

Comment: After that `values` is wrong so you should debug your traverse code. Looks like you do not make a tree to walk.

Answer (score 0):

After the corrections made in your question, there are still these issues:

- The code never *updates* `closestProximity` so the `if` condition on this variable will always be true.
- The main call passes `treeData.tree` to the function, but that function then treats that reference as a node object, never looking into the `nodes` property.
- The input data is not transformed into instances of `BST`, which means that you cannot navigate efficiently through the tree. Even if you would have a `node` object, then `node.left` is just a string, not an object, and you'd have to scan the `tree.nodes` array to locate the corresponding object.
- By first collecting the nodes into an array through `traverse` you lose any benefit from the binary search tree. The purpose of this data structure is to *avoid* having to visit *all* values.

Here is a correction of your code that addresses these issues:

```js
class BST {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}

function loadTree(tree) {
    const nodeMap = new Map(tree.nodes.map(node => [node.id, new BST(node.value)]));
    for (const node of tree.nodes) {
        nodeMap.get(node.id).left = nodeMap.get(node.left) ?? null;
        nodeMap.get(node.id).right = nodeMap.get(node.right) ?? null;
    }
    return nodeMap.get(tree.root);
}

function findClosestValueInBst(root, target) {
    let currentNode = root;
    let high = Infinity;
    let low = -Infinity;
    while (currentNode) {
        if (target < currentNode.value) {
            high = currentNode.value;
            currentNode = currentNode.left;
        } else {
            low = currentNode.value;
            currentNode = currentNode.right;
        }
    }
    return high - target < target - low ? high : low;
}

const treeData = {"target": 12,"tree": {"nodes": [{"id": "10", "left": "5", "right": "15", "value": 10},{"id": "15", "left": "13", "right": "22", "value": 15},{"id": "22", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 22},{"id": "13", "left": null, "right": "14", "value": 13},{"id": "14", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 14},{"id": "5", "left": "2", "right": "5-2", "value": 5},{"id": "5-2", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 5},{"id": "2", "left": "1", "right": null, "value": 2},{"id": "1", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 1}],"root": "10"}}; 
const result = findClosestValueInBst(loadTree(treeData.tree), treeData.target);
console.log(result);
```